# How can I bold my font?

Tags: fonts

I want to use google web font "Michroma" which is very close to the Eurostile. Facing problem is Michroma don't have bold option in google web font. I want to make my headings "Bold render" on my web page. How can I bold my Michroma in CSS/HTML ?

Ref: http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Michroma

Answer (score 2):

in your CSS file

```
font-weight: 900;
```

EDIT:  Added  **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CzBBR/)**, toggling the font-weight values between 100 and 900 shows the change to bold (granted, not extremely bold)

EDIT 2:  Added another **[Fiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/MuMj7/)** using text-shadow that makes the font much more bold.

```
p.hello {
  font-family: "Michroma";
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;  
}
```

Comment: Added a demo that shows this does change the font to slightly more bold (albeit perhaps not as bold as you'd like)

Comment: Like you said "bold as I like is not possible" agreed. I did with the help of shadow 1px shadow horizontally added.

But still want some other way...

Comment: Any other font similar to Eurostile but free and bold possible?

Comment: Added another fiddle demo using shadows, hopefully this works?

Comment: Ya I did this but I think that is only way to make michroma bold. Do you have any idea about font similar to Eurostile but free like google web font because eurostile is little expensive.